# How do I fill a shape created by random points (drawLine)?

Tags: java

I'm creating a game that has randomly drawn Asteroids (to give the Asteroids a jagged look). After research I've only found that you can fill primitive shapes. Does anyone know a method I could use to fill these shapes?

```
package view.game_object;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class Asteroid extends BaseGameObject {

   public static final int BASE_SIZE = 10;
   private final int fragmentCount;
   private final int[][] points;
   private final int level;

public Asteroid(int level, Random r) {
    this.level = level;
    this.setBound(level * Asteroid.BASE_SIZE);
    int sizeRange = (int) (this.getBound() / 2);
    this.fragmentCount = this.level * 6;
    // generate random points to draw
    this.setPosition(0, 0);
    this.points = new int[fragmentCount][2];
    ArrayList<Float> angleList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragmentCount; i++) {
        angleList.add(r.nextFloat() * (float) (Math.PI * 2));
    }
    Collections.sort(angleList);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
        // base point
        float x = r.nextInt(sizeRange) + this.getBound() - sizeRange / 3;
        // rotate
        float[] point = BaseGameObject.rotate(x, 0, this.getPosx(), this.getPosy(),
                angleList.get(i));
        this.points[i][0] = (int) point[0];
        this.points[i][1] = (int) point[1];
    }
}

public int getLevel() {
    return level;
}

@Override
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
        int nextPoint = i + 1;
        if (nextPoint >= this.points.length) {
            nextPoint = 0;
        }
        g.drawLine(Math.round(this.getPosx()) + this.points[i][0],
                Math.round(this.getPosy()) + this.points[i][1],
                Math.round(this.getPosx()) + this.points[nextPoint][0],
                Math.round(this.getPosy()) + this.points[nextPoint][1]
        );

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [Graphics methods to draw a polygon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillPolygon(int[],%20int[],%20int)). but you must 'transform' your points into a proper format `getXs()`, i didn't point that out, i'm pretty sure you can do this as good as i can =)

```
@Override
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.gray); //fillColor
    int[] xPoints = getXs(this.points);
    int[] yPoints = getYs(this.points);
    int nPoints = xPoints.length;
    g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);

}
```